# Sorting in MapReduce producing extra values

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to sort a series of integers which is in the following order:

```
A    2
B    9
C    4
....
....
Z    42
```

Following is the Mapper and Reducer code:

```
public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<Text, Text, IntWritable, Text>
    {
        public void map(Text key, Text value, OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
        {
            output.collect(new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(value.toString())), key);
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text>
    {
        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
        {
            output.collect(key, new Text(""));
        }
    }
```

But the output is producing lots of extra integers. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with the code?

Also, if possible point me to a good integer sort example using MapReduce.

Edit:

```
job.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

Comment: Can you share your entire code. need to know what InputFormat you are using and what is your logic. Dont you have duplicates fields in your data? How many reducers are you using?

Comment: Also tell how big is the data?

Comment: It is a very small data, max 20 integers spread in 4 files(5 integers in each). Just wanted to test the program. I have edited the source code to include input format. Check.

Comment: Seems fine to me as per the code and data you shared. Check if there are any extra files in the input path or any loops in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I tried according to your logic but using new APIS. The result is correct.

Note: 2nd parameter of reduce(...) function is `**Iterable**<Text>`

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;


public class q18076708 extends Configured implements Tool {
    static class MapClass extends Mapper<Text, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
        public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            context.write(new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(value.toString())),
                    key);
        }

    }

    static class Reduce extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
        static int xxx = -1;
        @Override
        public void reduce(IntWritable key, **Iterable**<Text> values,
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            context.write(key, new Text(""));
        }

    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        getConf().set("fs.default.name", "file:///");
        getConf().set("mapred.job.tracker", "local");
        Job job = new Job(getConf(), "Logging job");
        job.setJarByClass(getClass());

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("src/test/resources/testinput.txt"));
        FileSystem.get(getConf()).delete(new Path("target/out"), true);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("target/out"));

        job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new q18076708(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
A   2
B   9
C   4
Z   42
```

out put:

```
2
4
9
42
```